# .npmrc несколько пакетов из одного источника

Tags: npm

Есть пара приватных пакетов лежащих на gitlab

`@myorg/package1`
`@myorg/package2`

Хочется установить их в проект, но не понятно что писать в .npmrc.
C одним пакетом всё понятно:

> @myorg:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PACKAGE_1_ID/packages/npm/
> //gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PACKAGE_1_ID/packages/npm/:_authToken=AUTH_TOKEN

Если, по аналогии с тем как устанавливать пакеты из нескольких registry, просто вписать второй пакет вот так:

> @myorg:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PACKAGE_1_ID/packages/npm/
> //gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PACKAGE_1_ID/packages/npm/:_authToken=AUTH_TOKEN
>
> @myorg:registry=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PACKAGE_2_ID/packages/npm/
> //gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/PACKAGE_2_ID/packages/npm/:_authToken=AUTH_TOKEN

То `@myorg/package1`, абсолютно ожидаемо, устанавливаться перестает.

Comment: А вы уверены что для каждого пакета нужно путь прописывать? Не знаком с тем, как в этом плане устроен GitLab, но у меня для GitHub'а указано примерно следующее: `@smellyshovel:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=ghp_<мой токен>
`
То есть просто ссылка на скоуп, а оттуда уже тянется несколько пакетов

Comment: Спасибо. =https://gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm/ решило проблему.

Comment: Я в ответ перепишу, мало ли кому пригодится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Путь на скоуп нужно указывать без указания названия конкретного пакета:

```
@myorg:registry=gitlab.com/api/v4/packages/npm
```

NPM сам разберется, как резолвить имена пакетов, если их несколько.